# Why .where(:attribute => nil) checks for nil value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So here is the query, very simple:

```
field = :has_bill
value = nil
scoped.where(field => value)
```

And it outputs as:

```
(`electricity_profile_segment_summaries`.`has_swimming_pool` IN ('') OR `electricity_profile_segment_summaries`.`has_swimming_pool` IS NULL)
```

Which includes `nil` values and `0` values as well. Which is not correct, I would like to represent only `NULL` values from the table.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about manually limiting to `NULL` for the `nil` case?

```
if value.nil?
  scoped.where( "#{field} IS NULL" )
else
  scoped.where( field => value
end
```

Comment: It is. Not sure if there's a "good" workaround for the default nil/SQL conversion, but will be interested to hear from others.